# Unit Testing the date function using Jasmine in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, date, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a function using date as a argument in **Angular**. Angular uses **jasmine** as a testing Framework.

I have a function like below that involves date manipulation

```
getDate(date) {
    const d = new Date(date);
    d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return d;
  }
```

I want to write unit Test for the above function using jasmine I have written following test.

```
describe('Service', () => {
  let testMockDate: Date;
  beforeEach(() => {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    jasmine.clock().install();
    testMockDate = new Date('2019-09-15T05:00:00Z');
    jasmine.clock().mockDate(testMockDate);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [Service]
    });
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
  });

  it('check date', inject(
      [Service],
      (service: Service) => {
        const dateString = service.getDate(testMockDate);
        expect(dateString).toEqual('2019-09-15T00:00:00Z');
      }
   ));
});
```

This test is passing in my local but on the server where timezone is different it is failing.
How can effectively test this function. I thought passing argument to date constructor would give me
same date in different timezone. but values depends upon the timezone. Although I am also mocking date using Jasmine but I am not sure it working correctly.

Comment: I got the same issue, wonder why it didn't got any answer.

Comment: @RanjithVaratharajan I suspect that this might be, because aside from manipulating the system time or non-perfect and complex mocking constructs, there is no easy answer to this. Personally I fixed this by setting time as node.ENV variable for development (works on linux/mac only) and manipulating server time for the CI.